# How to apply target a category or subcategory id no. and apply different properties to it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am setting up a meta title for my website. I want to be able to apple different title for my categories and subcategories. examples below

if category id is 4 (use this title 'Buy from us')
if categey id is 6 (use this title 'Cars for sale in Canada')
if subcategori id is 324 (use this title 'Accessories in the best')
etc

i have tried this but didnt work

```html
 if (cat->id=3){
    $title .= ' in ' . config('country.name') .' for sale | Prices on Lata.ng | Buy and sell online';
}
    if (cat->id=6){
$title .= ' in ' . config('country.name') .' for Buy| Best on Yakata.ng |';
} 
    view()->share('title', $title); 
    return $title;
```

Comment: Your `if` statements contain assignments instead of equality checks: use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib to setup SEO Tags in laravel: https://github.com/artesaos/seotools

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if (cat->id==3){
    $title .= ' in ' . config('country.name') .' for sale | Prices on Lata.ng | Buy and sell online';
}
    if (cat->id==6){
$title .= ' in ' . config('country.name') .' for Buy| Best on Yakata.ng |';
}   
    view()->share('title', $title); 
    return $title;
```